# path in query parameter append to url in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, wamp

I am trying to make the below url

> http://localhost/base/path/to/redirect/1-2-master/list.xh

redirect to

> http://localhost/base/list.php?r=path/to/redirect/1-2-master

I have tried this. But I am getting 404 error.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)base/(.*)/list.xh$ $1base/list.php?r=$2 [NC,L]
```

But when I tested on http://htaccess.mwl.be/ and it is working fine

Comment: Looks fine to me so far. What does your http servers error log file say about the failing requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there is no `base/.htaccess` you can use this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(base)/(.+)/list\.xh$ $1/list.php?r=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```